# NotificationChannel playing wrong sound in Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I have this weird problem with NotificationChannel sound in devices running Android Oreo.

Lets say i have two sound files in my project raw directory:

```
a.mp3
c.mp3
```

Then on first installation of an app i assign those sounds to different notification channels using their uri (for example):

```
android.resource://myapp/2131558403 (for sound a.mp3)
android.resource://myapp/2131558404 (for sound c.mp3)
```

At this point everything works as expected. 
Problem appears when i start adding new sounds (in front or in the middle):

```
a.mp3
B.mp3 <- new file
c.mp3
```

Resource IDs then change for the files accordingly:

```
android.resource://myapp/2131558403 (for sound a.mp3)
android.resource://myapp/2131558404 (for sound B.mp3)
android.resource://myapp/2131558405 (for sound c.mp3)
```

So at this point my second notification channel starts playing B.mp3 sound file instead of c.mp3 because it was initialized with android.resource://myapp/**2131558404** uri.

Resource id for for c.mp3 has shifted after compiling an app with new sound file.

So what would be solution for this problem since i can not modify notification channel after it was created.

Most obvious solution would be not to add new files in the middle of the old ones but could be forgotten.

Maybe i could delete old channel and add it again with new id?

Or is there a way to make raw files to have constant resource id?

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Not really. Just for now i am not removing unused audio files and making sure that the new ones is added to the end by assigning the names like that: z001_some_file; z002_another_one; Not a best solution but since i do not change sounds that often it is not that big of a deal. It is just annoying that i can not delete unused files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource ids change randomly, but notification channels cannot be changed. To combat this, you need to give the notification channel a symbolic uri to the file that does NOT reference the resource id.

That is, instead of referencing `R.raw.notification`:

```kotlin
val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                  context.applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.notification)
```

You should reference it like this:

```kotlin
val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + "/raw/notification")
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796493/5301868

Answer (score 2):

NotificationChannels are persistent. When making such changes, you would need to give the channel a different ID for the change to be picked up.

Comment: Only change I am making is adding a new audio file to a project. So you suggest me to delete old notification channels and recreate them with different ID every time I add or remove some audio file from a project?