# Android Notification Channel sounds stop working when using sound URIs that reference resource ids

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

We have created notification channels for devices running on Oreo and above, that use a custom notification sound that is located in our `/res/raw` folder. Recently, when users upgraded our app, the notification sound just stopped working and the notification only vibrates the device.

We have confirmed that uninstall/reinstall or clearing app data resolves the issue. However, in order to get notification sounds to work for everyone again without having to reinstall, we need to essentially delete and recreate these channels.

We create the notification channel as follows:

```
fun initNotificationChannel(channel: PSSNotificationChannel) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val id = channel.id
            val name = context.getString(channel.nameResId)
            val importance = channel.importance
            val channel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)

            ...

            // Default sound
            val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.notification)
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build()
            channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes)

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
```

I have verified that the file still exists in `/res/raw`. And the commit that seemed to cause this was just some added/modified files to the `/res` folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like this issue setting the `soundUri` as follows:

```
val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.notification)
```

It looks like the value of `R.raw.notification` changed from `2131689979` (version where sound works) to `2131755515` (version where sound doesn't work). And since you can't change your notification sound with Notification Channels, I am almost certain that the channel is trying to resolve the `soundUri` with the old resource id (`android.resource://our.package.name/2131689979`).

I think the better approach is to reference the file directly by name as follows:

```
val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + "/raw/notification")
```

I also notice apps like Facebook Messenger and Slack use a public Notifications folder where they probably just copy the file over and reference that exact path. This also seems to allow the user to re-select the app-provided sound because it is visible in the filesystem.

Comment: That was it! I've been looking at this for some time. First the App provided sound worked perfectly but then it just stopped, usually after a few weeks. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried setting the sound of the Notification Channel in the manner you suggested by using thes tring name directly, but I'm still getting a FileNotFound exception with it attempting to look for the old resource id. (i.e. `MediaPlayer: Couldn't open android.resource://<appname>/2131099651: java.io.FileNotFoundException`) What is actually mapping from the channel id in the push to the sound uri?

Comment: It turns out using a string in the uri does work even if resource ids change, but only if upgrading from another app version which also used a string based uri. So if your previous version used resource ids in the uri, a newer version with string based uri's won't work.

Comment: I found an android issue opened for this. Please star if you have encountered this issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131303134

Comment: @efeder yeah, we had to migrate all users to the new notification channels with the string-based resources. We did this by adding a `version` suffix to our channel ids, so we could find/delete old channels and create the new ones, if they do not exist.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up deleting + recreating channels with new ids as well!