# Android no sound for notification after publishing the app

Tags: android, notifications

I am sending a notifications via Firebase and I have issues with the sound. I've tried more solutions found on this forum, but still did not help.

The problem is - the sound is WORKING when I debug the app on my device, but the sound is NOT working after I publish my app to store... and this is what I don't understand.

The code:

```
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notify)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentIntent(pi);

    NotificationManager manager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    assert manager != null;
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

I want to play a default sound, nothing custom. No clue why it is working when testing and not working when published.

Comment: What API level?

Comment: testing on 26. I am using also channel if build version is O and higher. Now I added this:  nChan.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI,attributes); still not sure if this help (will test after next release), but why it is working also without this line on API 26 when testing and not working when published

Comment: I think it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796492/android-notification-channel-sounds-stop-working-when-using-sound-uris-that-refe/54796493#54796493), but I'd ask you to confirm that before I post an answer. If this is actually the case, your next push, with `DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI`, will **not** work, and I recommend using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340580/6759241) to fix. You will also have to start with a fresh notification channel. You can either delete the original (`deleteNotificationChannel()`), or you can create a new one with a new, unique channel `id`.

Comment: your first link is about a custom raw.notification and the second link is about image resource. I need to use a default sound for each device

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. _Sometimes_ this bug is caused by the resource URI that's been persisted to the `NotificationChannel` getting "broken". If, for example, you used a different URI in an earlier version of the app, or if, say, your phone got upgraded, thereby changing the return value of `RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)`, then the old, broken URI stays in the `NotificationChannel`, no matter how many times you re-create it. You have to delete the channel entirely (or uninstall the app) in order to reset the URI.

Comment: hmm, ok then, I created a new channel ID. Again, it is working when testing, I will check if this will work after publishing. Before I have uninstalled my app and installed a new instance, but the notification sound was still not working, so let's see if the new channel id will help