# Android app - updated version trying to access old resources

Tags: android, push-notification, resources

we are using OneSignal to send push notifications to devices using our app. I am in the process of converting it to FCM which has mostly been painless except I have one issue. With my new apk (v2.8) if I install it on a device with the current version (v2.7) of our app installed then the notification sounds don't work. It vibrates but there is no sound (we are using 2 custom sounds). If I then clear the data, i.e. via settings/apps../Storage/Clear Data then the sounds start working as expected. If I install on a device that doesn't have the app installed already then it works properly. This only seems to be a problem on devices running Oreo and Pie. I have a Samsung S4 Mini which does not have the issue.

Further to this issue, when I delve into the logcat after sending a test push notification I see the following error:
2019-03-27 11:02:40.978 5019-21507/? E/FileSource: Failed to open file 'android.resource://staffsync.reliever/2131492871'. (No such file or directory)

Using the APK Analyser I found that the resource ID 2131492871 actually belongs to the raw sound file the test notification is trying to play **but** from the previous version of the apk, i.e. the one this install updated - v2.7.

Why is it trying to access an old resource?
TIA for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this should be an answer or added to the question.  I got some clues from [Secolink Eu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781986/notificationchannel-playing-wrong-sound-in-oreo) and [Steve Strates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796492/android-notification-channel-sounds-stop-working-when-using-sound-uris-that-refe).

By digging around in the APK Analyzer in Android Studio, specifically the resources.arsc folder I've discovered the resources get assigned ids quite systematically - each resource of a given type will be in a series with the same first 4 numbers e.g. 0f0d, and the last 4 are assigned via the alphabetic order of the resource names/filenames in the type, so if I had a.mp3, b.mp3 and c.mp3 in my res/raw folder they would be assigned 0f0d001, 0f0d002 and 0f0d003 respectively. In this example if the preceding res type was menu then it would have 0f0c series resource ids and the proceeding type - string - would have 0f0e.

If your underlying folder/file structure doesn't change from build to build then the chances are you'll end up with the same IDs from one build to the next... easy
But in my case in my latest build all of my raw/res resources started with 0f0c, in the previous build they started with 0f0d, I had removed a res/menu folder that had nothing in it in the new build, in the old build that folder got assigned 0f0c ids.
So it seems the new build won't play the sounds because the device is accessing a totally different type of resource with the 0f0dxxxx ID. I believe this is retained even after an update because of the Oreo/Pie security changes. 
If I put back the deleted res/menu folder and restore the res/raw folder to how it was (I removed some sounds that we were not using) then my new build will work as expected. We can get the users to manually clear their data after installing the new app which fixes the problem but we have several thousand users, a large number of them wouldn't know how to do that so they ring support, and the ones that do won't be able to remember their login details... so they ring support.
This seems like quite a limitation with Oreo and Pie, I get that they are protecting the user's preferences but maybe the install process should offer an option to allow the notification resource changes, or is there something I'm doing wrong, should I should put the sound files somewhere else?

Comment: I have run into this same issue.  Were you able to figure this out?